# Javascript CSS star rating system hover

Tags: javascript, css, hover

I have written a code that's for star rating system. Each star has a data-attribute with its value in pixels based on its size. On the click of every star, this value is updated to recipe.rating array object (which represents some database in the future.). So this values is the width pixels of my inner rating star so they appear yellow when the respective grey gets clicked and vice-versa. The problem is that with this setup I have not found a way to hover over my stars so they become yellow or grey on hover.

there would be anyway of doing that?
is my code broken and its better I restructure it differently?

code => https://codepen.io/notnishi/pen/ExKjPbj

```js
const recipe = [{
  rating: 0 // <-- must accept numbers from 0 to 5 | strings 0% to 100% | 0.1 to 5.0 and converted.
}];

const stars = document.querySelectorAll('.starOutter'); //  [...stars][0].id

stars.forEach(star => star.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  recipe.rating = parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('data-rate'));

  document.querySelector('.stars-inner').style.width = `${recipe.rating}px`;
  console.log(recipe.rating);
  //i should click on something that doesnt dissapear but i must clck on the right star.
  // well, i dont necessarily need to click on the inner star. i can click on the outter.
}));

//now i have to have another function that clicks back the width of the inner star so the star backs to grey.

const starsInner = document.querySelectorAll('.star');


starsInner.forEach(star => star.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  recipe.rating = parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('data-rate'));

  document.querySelector('.stars-inner').style.width = `${recipe.rating}px`;
  console.log(recipe.rating);
}));
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.stars-outter {
  fill: #aaa;
  position: relative;
}

.stars-inner {
  fill: gold;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 270px;
  /* 25px -> 55px -> 85px -> 115px -> 145px */
}


/* 
svg {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
} */
```

```html
<div class="stars-outter">
  <svg class="starOutter" height="25px" width="25px" viewBox="0 -10 511.98685 511">
    <path data-rate="25" d="m510.652344 185.902344c-3.351563-10.367188-12.546875-17.730469-23.425782-18.710938l-147.773437-13.417968-58.433594-136.769532c-4.308593-10.023437-14.121093-16.511718-25.023437-16.511718s-20.714844 6.488281-25.023438 16.535156l-58.433594 136.746094-147.796874 13.417968c-10.859376 1.003906-20.03125 8.34375-23.402344 18.710938-3.371094 10.367187-.257813 21.738281 7.957031 28.90625l111.699219 97.960937-32.9375 145.089844c-2.410156 10.667969 1.730468 21.695313 10.582031 28.09375 4.757813 3.4375 10.324219 5.1875 15.9375 5.1875 4.839844 0 9.640625-1.304687 13.949219-3.882813l127.46875-76.183593 127.421875 76.183593c9.324219 5.609376 21.078125 5.097657 29.910156-1.304687 8.855469-6.417969 12.992187-17.449219 10.582031-28.09375l-32.9375-145.089844 111.699219-97.941406c8.214844-7.1875 11.351563-18.539063 7.980469-28.925781zm0 0"/>
  </svg>

  <svg class="starOutter" height="25px" width="25px" viewBox="0 -10 511.98685 511">
    <path data-rate="55" d="m510.652344 185.902344c-3.351563-10.367188-12.546875-17.730469-23.425782-18.710938l-147.773437-13.417968-58.433594-136.769532c-4.308593-10.023437-14.121093-16.511718-25.023437-16.511718s-20.714844 6.488281-25.023438 16.535156l-58.433594 136.746094-147.796874 13.417968c-10.859376 1.003906-20.03125 8.34375-23.402344 18.710938-3.371094 10.367187-.257813 21.738281 7.957031 28.90625l111.699219 97.960937-32.9375 145.089844c-2.410156 10.667969 1.730468 21.695313 10.582031 28.09375 4.757813 3.4375 10.324219 5.1875 15.9375 5.1875 4.839844 0 9.640625-1.304687 13.949219-3.882813l127.46875-76.183593 127.421875 76.183593c9.324219 5.609376 21.078125 5.097657 29.910156-1.304687 8.855469-6.417969 12.992187-17.449219 10.582031-28.09375l-32.9375-145.089844 111.699219-97.941406c8.214844-7.1875 11.351563-18.539063 7.980469-28.925781zm0 0"/>
  </svg>

  <svg class="starOutter" height="25px" width="25px" viewBox="0 -10 511.98685 511">
    <path data-rate="85" d="m510.652344 185.902344c-3.351563-10.367188-12.546875-17.730469-23.425782-18.710938l-147.773437-13.417968-58.433594-136.769532c-4.308593-10.023437-14.121093-16.511718-25.023437-16.511718s-20.714844 6.488281-25.023438 16.535156l-58.433594 136.746094-147.796874 13.417968c-10.859376 1.003906-20.03125 8.34375-23.402344 18.710938-3.371094 10.367187-.257813 21.738281 7.957031 28.90625l111.699219 97.960937-32.9375 145.089844c-2.410156 10.667969 1.730468 21.695313 10.582031 28.09375 4.757813 3.4375 10.324219 5.1875 15.9375 5.1875 4.839844 0 9.640625-1.304687 13.949219-3.882813l127.46875-76.183593 127.421875 76.183593c9.324219 5.609376 21.078125 5.097657 29.910156-1.304687 8.855469-6.417969 12.992187-17.449219 10.582031-28.09375l-32.9375-145.089844 111.699219-97.941406c8.214844-7.1875 11.351563-18.539063 7.980469-28.925781zm0 0"/>
  </svg>

  <svg class="starOutter" height="25px" width="25px" viewBox="0 -10 511.98685 511">
    <path data-rate="115" d="m510.652344 185.902344c-3.351563-10.367188-12.546875-17.730469-23.425782-18.710938l-147.773437-13.417968-58.433594-136.769532c-4.308593-10.023437-14.121093-16.511718-25.023437-16.511718s-20.714844 6.488281-25.023438 16.535156l-58.433594 136.746094-147.796874 13.417968c-10.859376 1.003906-20.03125 8.34375-23.402344 18.710938-3.371094 10.367187-.257813 21.738281 7.957031 28.90625l111.699219 97.960937-32.9375 145.089844c-2.410156 10.667969 1.730468 21.695313 10.582031 28.09375 4.757813 3.4375 10.324219 5.1875 15.9375 5.1875 4.839844 0 9.640625-1.304687 13.949219-3.882813l127.46875-76.183593 127.421875 76.183593c9.324219 5.609376 21.078125 5.097657 29.910156-1.304687 8.855469-6.417969 12.992187-17.449219 10.582031-28.09375l-32.9375-145.089844 111.699219-97.941406c8.214844-7.1875 11.351563-18.539063 7.980469-28.925781zm0 0"/>
  </svg>

  <svg class="starOutter" height="25px" width="25px" viewBox="0 -10 511.98685 511">
    <path data-rate="145" d="m510.652344 185.902344c-3.351563-10.367188-12.546875-17.730469-23.425782-18.710938l-147.773437-13.417968-58.433594-136.769532c-4.308593-10.023437-14.121093-16.511718-25.023437-16.511718s-20.714844 6.488281-25.023438 16.535156l-58.433594 136.746094-147.796874 13.417968c-10.859376 1.003906-20.03125 8.34375-23.402344 18.710938-3.371094 10.367187-.257813 21.738281 7.957031 28.90625l111.699219 97.960937-32.9375 145.089844c-2.410156 10.667969 1.730468 21.695313 10.582031 28.09375 4.757813 3.4375 10.324219 5.1875 15.9375 5.1875 4.839844 0 9.640625-1.304687 13.949219-3.882813l127.46875-76.183593 127.421875 76.183593c9.324219 5.609376 21.078125 5.097657 29.910156-1.304687 8.855469-6.417969 12.992187-17.449219 10.582031-28.09375l-32.9375-145.089844 111.699219-97.941406c8.214844-7.1875 11.351563-18.539063 7.980469-28.925781zm0 0"/>
  </svg>

  <div class="stars-inner">
    <svg class="star" height="25px" width="25px" viewBox="0 -10 511.98685 511">
    <path data-rate="25" d="m510.652344 185.902344c-3.351563-10.367188-12.546875-17.730469-23.425782-18.710938l-147.773437-13.417968-58.433594-136.769532c-4.308593-10.023437-14.121093-16.511718-25.023437-16.511718s-20.714844 6.488281-25.023438 16.535156l-58.433594 136.746094-147.796874 13.417968c-10.859376 1.003906-20.03125 8.34375-23.402344 18.710938-3.371094 10.367187-.257813 21.738281 7.957031 28.90625l111.699219 97.960937-32.9375 145.089844c-2.410156 10.667969 1.730468 21.695313 10.582031 28.09375 4.757813 3.4375 10.324219 5.1875 15.9375 5.1875 4.839844 0 9.640625-1.304687 13.949219-3.882813l127.46875-76.183593 127.421875 76.183593c9.324219 5.609376 21.078125 5.097657 29.910156-1.304687 8.855469-6.417969 12.992187-17.449219 10.582031-28.09375l-32.9375-145.089844 111.699219-97.941406c8.214844-7.1875 11.351563-18.539063 7.980469-28.925781zm0 0"/>
  </svg>

    <svg id="20" class="star" height="25px" width="25px" viewBox="0 -10 511.98685 511">
    <path data-rate="55" d="m510.652344 185.902344c-3.351563-10.367188-12.546875-17.730469-23.425782-18.710938l-147.773437-13.417968-58.433594-136.769532c-4.308593-10.023437-14.121093-16.511718-25.023437-16.511718s-20.714844 6.488281-25.023438 16.535156l-58.433594 136.746094-147.796874 13.417968c-10.859376 1.003906-20.03125 8.34375-23.402344 18.710938-3.371094 10.367187-.257813 21.738281 7.957031 28.90625l111.699219 97.960937-32.9375 145.089844c-2.410156 10.667969 1.730468 21.695313 10.582031 28.09375 4.757813 3.4375 10.324219 5.1875 15.9375 5.1875 4.839844 0 9.640625-1.304687 13.949219-3.882813l127.46875-76.183593 127.421875 76.183593c9.324219 5.609376 21.078125 5.097657 29.910156-1.304687 8.855469-6.417969 12.992187-17.449219 10.582031-28.09375l-32.9375-145.089844 111.699219-97.941406c8.214844-7.1875 11.351563-18.539063 7.980469-28.925781zm0 0"/>
  </svg>

    <svg id="20" class="star" height="25px" width="25px" viewBox="0 -10 511.98685 511">
    <path data-rate="85" d="m510.652344 185.902344c-3.351563-10.367188-12.546875-17.730469-23.425782-18.710938l-147.773437-13.417968-58.433594-136.769532c-4.308593-10.023437-14.121093-16.511718-25.023437-16.511718s-20.714844 6.488281-25.023438 16.535156l-58.433594 136.746094-147.796874 13.417968c-10.859376 1.003906-20.03125 8.34375-23.402344 18.710938-3.371094 10.367187-.257813 21.738281 7.957031 28.90625l111.699219 97.960937-32.9375 145.089844c-2.410156 10.667969 1.730468 21.695313 10.582031 28.09375 4.757813 3.4375 10.324219 5.1875 15.9375 5.1875 4.839844 0 9.640625-1.304687 13.949219-3.882813l127.46875-76.183593 127.421875 76.183593c9.324219 5.609376 21.078125 5.097657 29.910156-1.304687 8.855469-6.417969 12.992187-17.449219 10.582031-28.09375l-32.9375-145.089844 111.699219-97.941406c8.214844-7.1875 11.351563-18.539063 7.980469-28.925781zm0 0"/>
  </svg>

    <svg id="20" class="star" height="25px" width="25px" viewBox="0 -10 511.98685 511">
    <path data-rate="115" d="m510.652344 185.902344c-3.351563-10.367188-12.546875-17.730469-23.425782-18.710938l-147.773437-13.417968-58.433594-136.769532c-4.308593-10.023437-14.121093-16.511718-25.023437-16.511718s-20.714844 6.488281-25.023438 16.535156l-58.433594 136.746094-147.796874 13.417968c-10.859376 1.003906-20.03125 8.34375-23.402344 18.710938-3.371094 10.367187-.257813 21.738281 7.957031 28.90625l111.699219 97.960937-32.9375 145.089844c-2.410156 10.667969 1.730468 21.695313 10.582031 28.09375 4.757813 3.4375 10.324219 5.1875 15.9375 5.1875 4.839844 0 9.640625-1.304687 13.949219-3.882813l127.46875-76.183593 127.421875 76.183593c9.324219 5.609376 21.078125 5.097657 29.910156-1.304687 8.855469-6.417969 12.992187-17.449219 10.582031-28.09375l-32.9375-145.089844 111.699219-97.941406c8.214844-7.1875 11.351563-18.539063 7.980469-28.925781zm0 0"/>
  </svg>

    <svg id="20" class="star" height="25px" width="25px" viewBox="0 -10 511.98685 511">
    <path data-rate="145" d="m510.652344 185.902344c-3.351563-10.367188-12.546875-17.730469-23.425782-18.710938l-147.773437-13.417968-58.433594-136.769532c-4.308593-10.023437-14.121093-16.511718-25.023437-16.511718s-20.714844 6.488281-25.023438 16.535156l-58.433594 136.746094-147.796874 13.417968c-10.859376 1.003906-20.03125 8.34375-23.402344 18.710938-3.371094 10.367187-.257813 21.738281 7.957031 28.90625l111.699219 97.960937-32.9375 145.089844c-2.410156 10.667969 1.730468 21.695313 10.582031 28.09375 4.757813 3.4375 10.324219 5.1875 15.9375 5.1875 4.839844 0 9.640625-1.304687 13.949219-3.882813l127.46875-76.183593 127.421875 76.183593c9.324219 5.609376 21.078125 5.097657 29.910156-1.304687 8.855469-6.417969 12.992187-17.449219 10.582031-28.09375l-32.9375-145.089844 111.699219-97.941406c8.214844-7.1875 11.351563-18.539063 7.980469-28.925781zm0 0"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Confused by "so they become yellow or grey on hover" while in your code they're yellow by default, and red on hover. Do you want them yellow by default, and red on hover but you haven't found a way to color (red) the stars prior to the one that's hovered?

Comment: this red thing is for test purpose. I have my star outter and my star inner. The inner overlaps the outter as its width changes. I want to add a hover state so they visually becomes yellow as I hover. I do not think I can dinamically change the width of my css as i hover, so i though about change each nd every star that is before my hovered ones, but the problem is that there is no selector on CSS that selects the siblings that comes before, only after (+ and ~ respectively)

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that with this setup I have not found a way to hover over my stars so they become yellow or grey on hover.

You forgot to change your event listeners from `click` to `mouseover`. Change these lines

```js
 star.addEventListener("click", (e) => { ...
```

to

```js
star.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => { ...
```

[image: Edit lucid-paper-f6wmw]

Comment: yeah. i will have to do some workaround with hover.